# Is there a photo of Kurt Busiek dressed as Galactus?

Tags: marvel, galactus

I saw a photo from way back of Kurt Busiek dressed as Galactus, or rather in Big G's helmet, at least.

As far as I can recall, he was in his almost-trademark Hawaiian shirt, so it's not a cosplay or Halloween thing.

Where I can find a copy of the photo? I've searched but haven't been able to find it.

Comment: If you're not happy with people editing your question (in this instance, to improve it), you're on the wrong site

Comment: Also, insulting people is 'not nice' which is against our [code of conduct](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/conduct). Don't do that.

Comment: You're sure it's a Hawai'ian shirt? https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=763549448569368&set=pb.100047429588235.-2207520000.&type=3&locale=zh_TW

Comment: @RogerStevens Stop insulting other users.

Answer (score 5):

These appear on what seems to be his personal Facebook. I will not provide a direct link because it seems weird.

[image: Possibly Kurt Busiek and possibly a Galactus helmet]

[image]

Comment: I was about to say something about referencing the comment in the question, but then I realised you actually posted your answer 8 seconds _before_ the comment was posted.